# verifying an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Consider the function defined by: $$\langle p,q\rangle=2a_1b_1+a_2b_2$$ where $$p(x)=a_1+a_2x$$  and $$q(x)= b_1+b_2x $$

a) Verify that $$\langle p,q\rangle$$ defines an inner product on $\mathbb R.$

well thats the question, which ive kinda like a revision for my final exam soon. but im having a trouble solving it. i know i've like few rules to verify in order to prove that $$\langle p,q\rangle$$ defines an inner product. ive already solved 1st one $$\langle p,q\rangle=\langle q,p\rangle$$
$$\langle p,q\rangle=2a_1b_1+a_2b_2$$
     $$=a_2b_2+2a_1b_1$$
     $$=\langle q,p\rangle$$
which prove 1st rule$$ \langle p,q\rangle=\langle q,p\rangle $$ Not sure if its true ..

but im having a problem in the 2nd one where i should prove 
$$\langle p,q+z\rangle =\langle p,q\rangle+\langle p,z\rangle$$ ( where i define z and it should look like ) $$z(x)=c_1+c_2x$$

I'm having a problem which is i dont know to which part of $\langle p,q\rangle$ i should add the $z$

and if 1st rule verification is wrong.. inform me please
thank you for your time

Comment: Please check [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to write mathematics on this site, and you will get far more positive responses. At the moment, it's unclear how you've defined everything.

Comment: @BillWallis thank you for your answer, ill check it out and see if i can improve my question.

Comment: The most basic rule that will help a lot is that maths is always written between dollar `$` signs. You can use `^` for superscripts and `_` for subscripts.

Comment: i updated the look of the question.. sorry about the mess before , it seems if i dont use the $$ some stuff wont show up.. i hope u take a look a it now.

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle p,q\rangle = \langle q,p\rangle,$ not $<p,q>=<q,p>.$ If you google "latex symbols" you can find things like that.

Answer (score 1):

To verify that something is  an "inner product" you have to show that it satisfies the definition of "inner product".  And that is:
1)   is linear in the first variable.  That is, that = a+ b.

2) That  is "symmetric" if the field is the real numbers: =  or "conjugate symmetric" if the field is the complex numbers: = the complex conjugate of .

3) That  is a positive real number for every v.

1) With $u= a_1+ b_1X$, $v= a_2+ b_2X$, and $w= a_3+ b_3X, $u+ v= (a_1+ a_2)+ (b_1+ b_2)X$ so that $= 2(a_1+ a_2)(b_1+ b_2)+ a_3b_3$.  $= 2a_1b_1+ a_3b_3$ and $= 2a_2b_2+ a_3b_3$. $+ = 2a_1b_1+ 2a_2b_2+ 2a_3b_3$.  NO, that is not the same as .  This is NOT an inner product!

Are you sure you copied the problem correctly?  With $u= a_1+ b_1X$ and $v= a_2+ b_2X$, $<u, v>= 2a_1a_2+ b_1b_2$ would make more sense.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for $\langle$ and $\rangle$ respectively, or put dollars around $<$ and $>$. The use of `<` and `>` outside of math mode is reserved for formatting commands and thus have not been displayed.

Comment: sorry for my mistake, i fixed it now with $p(x)=a_1+a_2x$ instead of $p(x)=a_1+b_2x$

Comment: u can check it over here https://ibb.co/bEKn6T